# Using the @RefreshScope annotation causes the cross-domain FilterRegistrationBean to fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am now solving cross-domain problems,I added a cross domain configuration，He is effective and solved the cross-domain problem for me，Now I want to refresh the cross-domain configuration in real time，So I used @RefreshScope annotation，But even the cross-domain configuration is invalid

I added a cross domain configuration

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class FilterConfiguration {
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowCredentials:true}")
    private boolean allowCredentials;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedHeader:*}")
    private String allowedHeader;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedMethod:*}")
    private String allowedMethod;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedOrigin:*}")
    private String allowedOrigin;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.corsPath:/**}")
    private String corsPath;

    /**
     * 跨域请求配置
     * @return
     */
    private CorsConfiguration buildCorsConfig() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(allowCredentials);
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader(allowedHeader);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(allowedMethod);
        //指定域名拦截配置
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(allowedOrigin) && !CorsConfiguration.ALL.equals(allowedOrigin)) {
            String[] originArr = allowedOrigin.split(",");
            for (String origin : originArr) {
                corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(origin);
            }
        } else {
            corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        }

        return corsConfig;
    }

    /**
     * 跨域请求过滤器配置
     */
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        //注：暂定所有接口均允许跨域,建议针对具体接口配置允许跨域
        configSource.registerCorsConfiguration(corsPath, buildCorsConfig());

        log.info("跨域请求过滤器配置:{}", JSONObject.toJSONString(configSource.getCorsConfigurations()));
        return new CorsFilter(configSource);
    }

    /**
     * 跨域请求配置注册至过滤器
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegist() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistration.setFilter(corsFilter());
        filterRegistration.setName("corsFilter");
        filterRegistration.setOrder(0);
        return filterRegistration;
    }
}
```

He is effective and solved the cross-domain problem for me，Now I want to refresh the cross-domain configuration in real time，So I used @RefreshScope annotation

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class FilterConfiguration {
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowCredentials:true}")
    private boolean allowCredentials;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedHeader:*}")
    private String allowedHeader;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedMethod:*}")
    private String allowedMethod;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.allowedOrigin:*}")
    private String allowedOrigin;
    @Value("${jlpay.business.filter.corsPath:/**}")
    private String corsPath;

    /**
     * 跨域请求配置
     * @return
     */
    private CorsConfiguration buildCorsConfig() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(allowCredentials);
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader(allowedHeader);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(allowedMethod);
        //指定域名拦截配置
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(allowedOrigin) && !CorsConfiguration.ALL.equals(allowedOrigin)) {
            String[] originArr = allowedOrigin.split(",");
            for (String origin : originArr) {
                corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(origin);
            }
        } else {
            corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        }

        return corsConfig;
    }

    /**
     * 跨域请求过滤器配置
     */
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        //注：暂定所有接口均允许跨域,建议针对具体接口配置允许跨域
        configSource.registerCorsConfiguration(corsPath, buildCorsConfig());

        log.info("跨域请求过滤器配置:{}", JSONObject.toJSONString(configSource.getCorsConfigurations()));
        return new CorsFilter(configSource);
    }

    /**
     * 跨域请求配置注册至过滤器
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilterRegist() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistration.setFilter(corsFilter());
        filterRegistration.setName("corsFilter");
        filterRegistration.setOrder(0);
        return filterRegistration;
    }
}
```

But he can't refresh the configuration in real time, and what's worse, he makes my cross-domain configuration invalid，A cross-domain error occurred when the front end accessed my interface，The error is as follows
`has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
I hope everyone can help me to solve it, thank you

Comment: Make your private method a public method and annotate with `@Bean` instaed of calling the method from your `corsFilter` method inject it into the method as a parameter.

Comment: first thank  you，I used your method，code show as below，Solved the cross-domain problem, but the configuration still cannot be refreshed in real time
```
/**
     * 跨域请求配置
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public CorsConfiguration buildCorsConfig() {
     }
        
```

Comment: Which is becauser you are using `@Value` where you should use configuration properties which are refreshed as well.

Comment: I'm so sorry I can't understand you，can you show me the code?